# Is there a counterexample such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n\ne \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, products

Suppose 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} = L_{1}, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n} = L_2 $$ 
Is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n} = L_{1}L_{2}$$ correct?
If not, is there any counterexample?

Comment: This is very incorrect

Comment: Why not try it on a simple case, like $a_n=b_n=1 / 2^n\,$.

Comment: An amusing thing to try might be $a_1=b_1=-\frac16,$ $a_n = b_n = \left(-\frac12\right)^n$ for $n\geq 2.$

Answer (score 4):

In general,
$$a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 \ne (a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2).$$

Comment: … unless $a_1b_2+a_2b_1=0$ …

Answer (score 2):

Take $L_1 =L_2 =\sum_{n>0} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$